# How can I differentiate $f(x,z(x,y))$ w. r. to x

Tags: derivatives

> How can I differentiate $f(x,z(x,y))$ w. r. to x

If $z(x,y)=c=\text{constant}$ and $\hat{y}=f(x,c)$ then what is $d\hat y/dx$

If I just differentiate $f$ w.r. to $x$ without knowing whether $z$ is constant or not $f_x(x,z(x,y))=f_x(z(x,y))=f_z(x,z(x,y))\cdot z_x(x,y)=\frac{\partial \hat y}{\partial z}z_x(x,y)=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial z}{\partial \hat y}}\cdot z_x(x,y)=\frac{z_x(x,y)}{z_y(x,y)}$

but the result should be negative

It is here on page 10 (18) Question 2.4 https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B21HoBq6u9TsWGtxWnNqVGtCSnM/edit?pref=2&pli=1&embedded=true

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your notation is not clear. You have to distinguish between the total derivative ($\frac{d}{dx}$) and partial derivatives($\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$). $f_x$ and $f_z$ are abbreviations for the partial derivatives w.r.t.\ $x$ and $z$. For calculating the total derivative you have to use the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x,z(x,y)) = f_x(x,z(x,y)) + f_z(x,z(x,y))z_x(x,y).
$$
In case $z$ is constant, the partial derivative $z_x$ vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the derivative wrong. You need to use the chain rule. Here $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,z(x,y)) = f_x(x,z(x,y)) + f_y(x,z(x,y)) z_x(x,y).$$ In the case that $z = c,$ constant, we have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,c) = f_x(x,c). $$

Answer (score 0):

Engrave this method to memory. I find that I never forget it this way;

$$\frac{d}{dt} \  f(\vec{c}(t))  = \nabla f|_{\vec{c}(t)} \cdot \vec{c}'(t)$$

Just let $\vec{c}(x,y) = \langle x,z(x,y) \rangle$ then differentiating with respect to $x$, allows you to view $\vec{c}(x,y)$ as just a function of $x$ say $c(x)$. Then we have;

$$\frac{d}{dt} \ f(\vec{c}(x)) = \langle f_x,f_y \rangle|_{\vec{c}(x)} \cdot \langle 1,z_x(x,y) \rangle$$